# How to show divs with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I need to show only specific divs in aone page. I want to put all the divs in the page and that I will have a button that change which divs the browser shows every time.

**This is my code:**

```html
<div class="all red">content..</div>
<div class="all blue">content..</div>
<div class="all red">content..</div>
<div class="all green">content..</div>
<div class="all blue">content..</div>
```

All stands for an option to show all the divs and every div has its own seperate class that I want choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do like this , you have to use [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) -for showing div, and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)-for hiding div  method of jquery

```
$("div.red").show();--this show red
$("div.blue").show();--this show blue
$("div.green").show();--this show green
```

Comment: And how do I connect it to a button?

Comment: @boltan have you done any research yourself so far? There are things like eventhandlers that let you connect a button to an event (click) and then to an action (hiding / showing your divs)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, it gets lot easier. Simply set the initial display of all the classes you want hidden to "none"

```
.red{
     display:none; 
}
```

And then set the display to block in your event handler function.

```
$(".red").css("display","block");
```

Hopefully that solves it.